# Button to position the page based on anchor (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I have this anchor in my HTML:

```
<a name="MOVEHERE"></a>
```

and I have `Button1`. How can make pressing on `Button1` move the page to the position of `MOVEHERE` anchor?

Comment: use anchor instead button and apply css like button. and add attribute href="movehere" , that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

put the input inside a tag that href to #movehere  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QAmPT/2/)**

```
<a href="#movehere">
   <input type="button" id="button1" value="button1" />
</a>



<a name="MOVEHERE" href="#" id="movehere">move here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use anchor instead button and apply css like button. and add attribute href="movehere" , that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="but_move" value="ClickToMove" />
    <br />
    Top Of The Page
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a id="MOVEHERE">MOVEHERE</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    Bottom of The Page
    <script>
        $("#but_move").click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#MOVEHERE").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```